# Can't check balance of a user using ethersjs

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, ethers.js

```js
const lpERC20 = new ethers.Contract(pairAddress, lpABI);
console.log(await lpERC20.callStatic.balanceOf(usr));
```

where `pairAddress` is `const pairAddress = await factory.getPair(tA.address, tB.address);`
and `lpABI` is

```js
const lpABI = [
  {
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: "address",
        name: "account",
        type: "address",
      },
    ],
    name: "balanceOf",
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "",
        type: "uint256",
      },
    ],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
];
```

`usr` is

```js
const signer = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider().getSigner();
const usr: string = await signer.getAddress();
```

The balanceOf function doesn't work - i get this error -
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of null`